# Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit, forms

I have a bog-standard login form - an email text field, a password field and a submit button on an AIR project that's using HTML/jQuery.  When I hit Enter on the form, the entire form's contents vanish, but the form isn't submitted.  Does anyone know if this is a Webkit issue (Adobe AIR uses Webkit for HTML), or if I've bunged things up?

I tried:

```
$('.input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('form#login').submit();
  }
});
```

But that neither stopped the clearing behavior, or submitted the form.  There's no action associated with the form - could that be the issue?  Can I put a javascript function in the action?

Comment: Do you really have a class="input" attribute on your <input...? Seems like it should be $('input').keypress...

Comment: The classes are generated programmatically by a CMS.  Other than that, however, scoping it to $('input') would affect every input on the page, regarless of whether I wanted the behavior or not.  Sorry it offends your sensibilities.

Comment: Sensibilities not offended in the least. Just thought it might have been an oversight that lead to the problem. Carry on.

Answer (score 453, accepted):

```
$('.input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('form#login').submit();
    return false;    //<---- Add this line
  }
});
```

Check out this stackoverflow answer:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Essentially, "return false" is the same as calling `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Note they are not the same. IE8 has no e.preventDefault. For IE8 use event.returnValue = false;

Comment: @mbokil Except that when using jQuery, it is the same in IE8. and IE7. And IE6.

Comment: If you want to type first into the input fields, put the "return false;" inside the if statement.

Answer (score 175):

In addition to return false as Jason Cohen mentioned.  You may have to also preventDefault

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: as @NoBrainer said, this is wrong: `return false` in an event managed by jQuery automatically call e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 85):

Don't know if it will help, but you can try simulating a submit button click, instead of directly submitting the form. I have the following code in production, and it works fine:

```
    $('.input').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            jQuery(this).blur();
            jQuery('#submit').focus().click();
        }
    });
```

Note: **jQuery('#submit').focus()** makes the button animate when enter is pressed.

Comment: Works great but I had to add "return false;" to prevent double form submission.

Comment: Working | See a LOT of results like this talking about trigger, sendkey, etc, doh, blah..., but that is the only works to me and really send a click on a button. Not submit().
So, the trick was focus().click() functions in secuence. THANK YOU.

Comment: Works, but i had to put this code under: $(document).ready(function() {...

Answer (score 62):

Return `false` to prevent the keystroke from continuing.

Answer (score 31):

Is there any reason you have to hook and test for the enter key?

Couldn't you simply add a

```
<input type="submit" />
```

to your form and have it naturally be submitted when enter is pushed? You could even then hook the form's `onsubmit` action and call a validation function from there if you wanted...

You could even use the `onsubmit` as a test to see if your form is being submitted, but it won't work if you call `form.submit()`.

Comment: Totally agree. My preference would always be to use the native functionality of the browser (inputs of type=submit natively respond to an enter key press) rather than adding further kludged up scripts..

Comment: Problem is, what if you are doing ajax stuff and there isn't an actual postback to the server, but you want the UI to behave as the user expects?

Comment: Indeed... I had overlooked the whole `return false;` thing.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a way to do this as a JQuery plugin (in case you want to re-use the functionality):

```
$.fn.onEnterKey =
    function( closure ) {
        $(this).keypress(
            function( event ) {
                var code = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;

                if (code == 13) {
                    closure();
                    return false;
                }
            } );
    }
```

Now if you want to decorate an `<input>` element with this type of functionality it's as simple as this:

```
$('#your-input-id').onEnterKey(
    function() {
        // Do stuff here
    } );
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also simply add `onsubmit="return false"` to the form code in the page to prevent the default behaviour.

Then hook (`.bind` or `.live`) the form's `submit` event to any function with jQuery in the javascript file.

Here's a sample code to help:

**HTML**

```
<form id="search_form" onsubmit="return false">
   <input type="text" id="search_field"/>
   <input type="button" id="search_btn" value="SEARCH"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search_form').live("submit", function() {
        any_function()
    });
});
```

This is working as of 2011-04-13, with Firefox 4.0 and jQuery 1.4.3

Answer (score 6):

This is my code:

```
  $("#txtMessage").on( "keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#frSendMessage").submit();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Also to maintain accessibility, you should use this to determine your keycode:

```
c = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;

if (c == 13) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I use now

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
...
}
```

At first I added an eventhandler to the submit button which produced an error for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding for easy implementation. You can simply make a form and then make the submit button hidden:

For example:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
Name : <input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

Comment: @cebirci and what version is your chrome? I tested from laptops to pc and my code just works. Try to download the newest chrome before you mark it down my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found out today the keypress event is not fired when hitting the Enter key, so you might want to switch to keydown() or keyup() instead.

My test script:

```
        $('.module input').keydown(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which;
            console.log("keydown ("+keyCode+")")
            if (keyCode == 13) {
                console.log("enter");
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('.module input').keyup(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which;
            console.log("keyup ("+keyCode+")")
            if (keyCode == 13) {
                console.log("enter");
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('.module input').keypress(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which;
            console.log("keypress ("+keyCode+")");
            if (keyCode == 13) {
                console.log("Enter");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The output in the console when typing "A Enter B" on the keyboard:

```
keydown (65)
keypress (97)
keyup (65)

keydown (13)
enter
keyup (13)
enter

keydown (66)
keypress (98)
keyup (66)
```

You see in the second sequence the 'keypress' is missing, but keydown and keyup register code '13' as being pressed/released.
As per [jQuery documentation on the function keypress()](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

```
Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.
```

Tested on IE11 and FF61 on Server 2012 R2

Comment: Just tested it on Chrome 90, Edge 90 and FF88.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it may be late
but you can add below line in html:-

```
<input onkeyup="submitForm(event)" oninput="addTextName(this)" type="text" id="name-val">
```

and add this on js file

```
function submitForm(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
if (keyCode == 13){
    toggleNextScreen();
}
```

}

keycode 13 means enter

Answer (score 1):

When the key is pressed, it will triggered event. if it is Enter key then it will block the action. Return false & preventDefault to prevent the keystroke.

```
$('form#login').keypress(function (e) {
   var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;       
   if (keyCode == 13) 
   {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('form#login').submit();
      return false; 
   }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML codes:

```
<form action="POST" onsubmit="ajax_submit();return false;">
    <b>First Name:</b> <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <br>
    <b>Last Name:</b> <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="send" onclick="ajax_submit();">
</form>
```

In Js codes:

```
function ajax_submit()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
            lastname: $("#lastname").val()
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr) {
            // another codes when result is success
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: @PaulRoub my answer have some difference with another.

Comment: How is this answer different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46490387) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46490427)?

Comment: @PaulRoub I have this problem and first search google for this. That pages, talk about this problem but not simple. When I find best answer, I decided share this on That pages talk about to help users when search this, see my answer on some similar stackoverflow pages.

Comment: this answer is not related to the question at all

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
var form = document.formname;

if($(form).length > 0)
{
    $(form).keypress(function (e){
        code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(code.toString() == 13) 
        {
             formsubmit();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This is mixing jquery with vanilla javascript in an uncomfortable way, and includes a really odd cast which just confuses things