# Trigger an event on `click` and `enter`

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a searchbox on my site that.  Currently, users must click the submit button next to the box to search via jquery's post.  I would like to let users also press enter to search.  How can i do this?

JQUERY:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#searchButton').click(function(){
        var search = $('#usersSearch').val();
        $.post('../searchusers.php',{search: search},function(response){
            $('#userSearchResultsTable').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='usersSearch'  /><input type='button' id='searchButton' value='search' />
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery

Comment: Yup, search function is useful...

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use `keypress` event on `usersSearch` textbox and look for <kbd>Enter</kbd> button. If enter button is pressed then trigger the search button click event which will do the rest of work. Try this.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#searchButton').click(function(){
        var search = $('#usersSearch').val();
        $.post('../searchusers.php',{search: search},function(response){
            $('#userSearchResultsTable').html(response);
        });
    })
    $('#usersSearch').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
            $('#searchButton').click();//Trigger search button click event
        }
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/ambCG/)**

Comment: Better yet: use the keyup event instead to ensure your function is only triggered once. Thanks to @StevePaulo for his comment in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/155263/461544).

Comment: A downside of using keyup that I just discovered: You won't be able to prevent the default action, because the keyup event is fired only _after_ the default action for the key has been executed (see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)).

Answer (score 75):

You call both event listeners using `.on()` then use a `if` inside the function:

```
$(function(){
  $('#searchButton').on('keypress click', function(e){
    var search = $('#usersSearch').val();
    if (e.which === 13 || e.type === 'click') {
      $.post('../searchusers.php', {search: search}, function (response) {
        $('#userSearchResultsTable').html(response);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why does this answer does not get more votes? I mean this is lesser code blocks (like not to add another event to trigger a click). Any downside of this?

Comment: Truly said, Nin-ya & sagarthapa.

Comment: You need to capture the keypress from the search field, and the click from the search button. Those are two separate DOM entities, and so this code won't work.

Comment: It worked for me but I had to add e.preventDefault() as a first line to prevent double execution

Comment: TIL: I can listen for multiple events with `on()`, Had no idea you could do that!

Answer (score 6):

Something like this will work

```
$('#usersSearch').keypress(function(ev){
    if (ev.which === 13)
        $('#searchButton').click();
});
```

Comment: but how can i use both, press search or press enter?

Comment: You put the code I added in addition to the code you already have. Then both will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#form').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { // If Enter key pressed
        $(this).trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below event of keypress on document load.

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
               yourfunction();
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `keypress` [function](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

I believe the `enter` key is `13` so you would want something like:

```
$('#searchButton').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){  //Enter is key 13
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#usersSearch').keyup(function() { // handle keyup event on search input field

    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;  // store browser agnostic keycode

    if(key == 13) 
        $(this).closest('form').submit(); // submit parent form
}
```