# Using GET Request submit form to the Page Itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url

What I need is when the user types his query in the search Box.

```
    <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus id="query" class="search-query search_input" placeholder="Type your query...">
    </form>
```

I dont have a Button to submit the form. I want the form to be submitted when the user presses the Enter Key.
And when the user presses the Enter key I want the Query to be shown in the URL.
Like the URL before the submission

```
http://example.come/
```

And when the user enters his text and presses the enter key. I want the query to be displayed in the URL like this

```
http://example.come/#query
```

Without reloading the whole.
Is this possile using the Javascript or Jquery or whatever is more easy.

Edit:
Here's what I tried 
         window.location.hash = get_query ;

```
 if (get_query.length != 0) {
      $("#query").val(get_query);
  $('.search_input').trigger('keyup'); // This is the Event which triggers 
  }
```

Comment: Yep, it is possible. Read docs and try something.

Comment: Dude I tried a few tricks ! But I really suck at it !!

Comment: Some browsers won't submit the form if there is no submit-button. However, look at this other Stackoverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery

Comment: Is it possible by using a hidden button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a input with type submit element which is hidden to support submitting by the enter key:

```
<form id="form1" class="navbar-search pull-left" action="">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus id="query" class="search-query search_input" placeholder="Type your query...">
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

On form submit change the hash with the value of the input:

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    window.location.hash = '#' + $("#query").val();
    return false;
});
```

Also see [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/LjYYK/show/) and the [associated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjYYK/).

Comment: What if I remove the "return false" statement cause I have a long statements which follows the .submit(function() ?

Comment: If you don't return `false` at the end of the submit handler, the form action will be executed (because it is empty the browser will reload the page). An alternative to returning `false` is setting the `action` attribute: `action="javascript:void(0);"`; then you can remove the `return false;`.

Comment: Also see the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/LjYYK/1/show/) with the [associated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjYYK/1/).