# php or javascript search in joomla

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I am hoping you guys can help me out I am sure its simple.

I want to make a joomla module or use one of the custom modules that allow me to add Javascript or Php(Not sure which I need to use for this).

What I want to do is have a text box and when that person types in something in that textbox it goes to that page.

For example:
I type in the text box: House for rent

And then the page that will open is: www.mywebsite.com/somesearch/house for rent

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear but assuming the page www.mywebsite.com/somesearch/searchtext is resolving to a page that can access the query string in the URL and process the search with the searchtext you can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$('#searchButton').click(function(){
   var searchText = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
   window.location.href = 'http://www.mywebsite/somesearch/'+encodeURIComponent(searchText);
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' id='searchBox' />
<input type='submit' id='searchButton' value='Search' />
</body>
</html>
```

You can use one of the available modules that let you write JavaScript, HTML or PHP code as a module listed here:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules

If you do this you can skip the html, head and body tags. Just put the `<script>...</script>` and then the `input`.

Also be careful processing the user input directly without escaping it against possible sql injection attacks.

Comment: Sorry, to be a clumsey here. But how do I press (go). (Enter) doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer to add the Search button. If you want Enter to work you can check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/699120/881232

Answer (score 0):

Question is very vague. So instead of providing all the code to make your own, I would recommend using an extension such as [RokAjaxSearch](http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokajaxsearch) which is a powerful search module that uses Ajax to prevent page refreshing. It also has the option to include Google results.

***Update***

You can also use the default Joomla search modules. In the Joomla backend, under **Components** (top menu) go to **Smart Search**, then click **Search Filter** on the ton tab. Add a new filter and set to **Search All**. Once done, go to the **Module Manager** and open the **Smart Search** module. Set a position for the module and select the filter you created before.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey. Yes, RoxAjaxSearch is awesome. I alraedy have a search. The problem is it is on a different page. So I want to Publish this search on another page. 

I want to know how would you go about taking text, redirecting that text to website/something/here is my search