# Ajax login not working on enter key

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, authentication

I have a login form in PHP which works on ajax, it works very well when i click on the login button, but not on pressing the enter key.

I did a lot of research on it and tried all the solutions posted on this site regarding the same and tried out all the solutions, but nothing is working for me.

My HTML is wrapped in a div id ="mini-login"

```
<div class="content-login">
<h4>Email Address:</h4>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<h4>Password:</h4>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="pasword"/>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo $forgotten; ?>"><?php echo $text_forgotten; ?></a><br />
<br />
 <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_login; ?>" id="button-login-mini" class="button" />
```

And my script-

```
$('#button-login-mini').live('click', function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=module/login/validate',
type: 'post',
data: $('#mini-login .content-login :input'),
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function() {
  $('#button-login-mini').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#button-login-mini').after('<span class="wait">Please wait</span>');
},  
complete: function() {
  $('#button-login-mini').attr('disabled', false);
  $('.wait').remove();
},        
success: function(json) {
  $('.warning, .error').remove();
  if (json['redirect']) {
    $('#mini-login .content-login').fadeOut('slow');
    location = json['redirect'];
  } else if (json['error']) {
    $('#mini-login .content-login').prepend('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error']['warning'] + '</div>');

    $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
  }
},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
}
}); 
});
```

So the above is working very well, but i tried to call it on enter key using- keyup, keydown, keypress and checking the keyCode==13, but it did not work, tried using forms as well, now going nuts over this!!! what am i doing wrong?? and how to make it work??

Note: The login page is not an entire document, it slides down on clicking login link on home page.

This is how the login page is called-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mini-login > .heading-login a').live('click', function() {
    $('#mini-login').addClass('active');

    $('#mini-login').load('index.php?route=module/login #mini-login > *');

    $('#mini-login').live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery

Comment: have you written any code for it .. ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra not working for me!! tried already!!

Comment: @new_developer- what do you mean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#mini-login > .heading-login a').live('click', function() {

 $(document).bind('keydown', function(e){         
    if (e.which == 13){
       $('#button-login-mini').trigger('click');   
   }     
      });


$('#mini-login').addClass('active');

$('#mini-login').load('index.php?route=module/login #mini-login > *');

$('#mini-login').live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(document).unbind('keydown');
});
});
});
```

Comment: It works, but it throws login error everytime i press enter, no matter whether i'm trying to login or not. It is submitting the form even if i'm not trying to login!!

Comment: your login div will be hidden until you press login button right .. ?

Comment: just edited my code .. try if it helps you  ....

Comment: check now ... tell me if error still pesists ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26840/discussion-between-new-developer-and-razor)

Answer (score 1):

Heres a code snippet i use with jQuery

```
            $(".login").keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    $("#loginBtn").click();
                }
            });
```

keyCode 13 = enter key the `#loginBtn` is the ID i attached to the button itself that calls th onClick and the `.login` is just the div class its held in.

hope this helps

Comment: My input field is not responding to enter key, i tried a simple alert, but doesnt work!!

Comment: Give me a minute to look into your code further.

Comment: I noticed that with my snippet on my application it doesnt want to work either with me when i press enter when inside a password field. Is it the same for you too or is it for any field?

Comment: Well i just tried Bipen answer bellow and that one worked for me alot better then mine did for myself Lol.. go figure. Go Bipen! lol... sorry about that Razor. Hopefully you get it figured out.

Comment: I have many search fields on my document and they all work fine on keyup or keydown and keycode==13, but its only the input fields in login which are not working!!

Comment: do you have any firebug console or google chrome browser to check for errors? I really dont see anything wrong with your code. And i just tried mine again, and it actually did work, i even simulated your code. Maybe if you an get a JSFiddle i can just get it working and comment where i made the changes. Without simulating your code exactly i dont think i am much of help. Im kind of new to this as well.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

use `trigger` to trigger the click event when pressed enter....

try this

```
  $(document).keypress(function(event){  // i called a clicked event in document here you can chnage it to any other event like.. input field keyup event or so....
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   if(keycode == '13'){
     $('#button-login-mini').trigger('click');   
   }

});
```

and use `on()` instead of live

```
$(document).on('click', '#button-login-mini',function() {....
```

closest static parent is preffered than document in on.... which in your case is `#content-login` i think

Comment: This gives same results as the solution given by new_developer above, no matter in which page i'm in, it is submitting the login form and giving login error even if i dont want to login

Comment: on top of that it is messing up with my search fields!!

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

you could actually call the event when you press enter in your email textbox or password textbox:

put your ajax code on a function and call it on your events:

```
function login(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=module/login/validate',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#mini-login .content-login :input'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-login-mini').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#button-login-mini').after('<span class="wait">Please wait</span>');
    },  
    complete: function() {
      $('#button-login-mini').attr('disabled', false);
      $('.wait').remove();
    },        
    success: function(json) {
      $('.warning, .error').remove();
      if (json['redirect']) {
        $('#mini-login .content-login').fadeOut('slow');
        location = json['redirect'];
      } else if (json['error']) {
        $('#mini-login .content-login').prepend('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error']['warning'] + '</div>');

        $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
    }); 
}

$document.ready(function(){
$('#button-login-mini').on('click', function() {
  login();
});
$('input[name="email"],input[name="password"]').bind('keypress',function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {
      login();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: With this, neither click works nor enter key

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look at it.