# Jquery: how to trigger click event on pressing enter key

Tags: jquery, key-events

I need to execute a button click event upon pressing key enter.

As it is at the moment the event is not firing.

Please Help me with the syntax if possible.

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='butAssignProd']", function () {
   //all the action
});
```

this is my attempt to fire click event on enter.

```
$("#txtSearchProdAssign").keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('input[name = butAssignProd]').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: You may have to include a return false or a `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: AS a side-note: `e.keyCode` is not completely cross browser. use `e.which` instead.

Comment: In this case, you SHOULD use `keyup` instead of `keypress` or `keydown`. `keypress`/`keydown` events trigger continuously while the key is pressed: http://jsbin.com/uzoxuk/1/edit

Comment: The modern way: `e.key === 'Enter'` (supported in all modern browsers and even IE9+).  I'll come back in another 7 years to post the new "modern" technique.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

try out this....

```
$('#txtSearchProdAssign').keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
    $('input[name = butAssignProd]').click();
    return false;  
  }
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[name="butAssignProd"]').click(function() {
    alert('Hello...!');
  });

  //press enter on text area..

  $('#txtSearchProdAssign').keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) // the enter key code
    {
      $('input[name = butAssignProd]').click();
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="txtSearchProdAssign"></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="butAssignProd" placeholder="click here">
</body>

</html>
```

---

[**Find Demo in jsbin.com**](http://jsbin.com/ijuvak/6/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: In case people want to recognize the "enter" keypress from anywhere, you can replace the $('#txtSearchProdAssign') and trigger on document $(document).keypress.......

Comment: Looks questionable from an accessibility perspective. Will this definitely work across all kind of devices having differing "selection" methods?

Answer (score 34):

Try This

```
$('#twitterSearch').keydown(function(event){ 
    var id = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode || 0;   
    if (id == 13) {
        $('#startSearch').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you

> **See also** stackoverflow.com/[`keyCode` vs `which`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4471582/8740349)

Comment: Did you mean `if((event.keyCode || event.which) == 13)`? yes, it's fully cross browser which supports `Tab` key in FF.

Comment: According to the [API](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/), `event.keyCode` is redundant, just use `event.which`.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('#txtSearchProdAssign').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('input[name = butAssignProd]').click();
    return false;  
  }
});
```

I also just found [Submitting a form on 'Enter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery?rq=1) which covers most of the issues comprehensively.

Answer (score 8):

You were almost there. Here is what you can try though.

```
$(function(){
  $("#txtSearchProdAssign").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('input[name="butAssignProd"]').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

I have used [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to execute click and bind it on the `keyup` event insted of `keydown` because `click` event comprises of two events actually i.e. `mousedown` then `mouseup`. So to resemble things same as possible with `keydown` and `keyup`.

Here is a [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ijuvak/1/edit)

Answer (score 7):

Another addition to make:

If you're dynamically adding an input, for example using `append()`, you must use the jQuery `on()` function.

```
$('#parent').on('keydown', '#input', function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13) {
        alert("enter");
        $('#button').click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

An even more efficient way of doing this would be to use a switch statement. You may find it cleaner, too.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="my-form">
  <input id="my-input" type="text">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.my-form').on('keydown', '#my-input', function (e) {
  var key = e.which;
  switch (key) {
  case 13: // enter
    alert('Enter key pressed.');
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
});
```

Comment: IMO using a switch statement for a single condition is overkill.

Comment: It's more efficient than an if statement, though.

Comment: I don't believe you. Can you cite a source?

Answer (score 5):

This is my preferred solution.

```
    $("#text").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            $("#submit").click();
        }
    });
```

Super simple, super jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Just include preventDefault() function in the code,

```
$("#txtSearchProdAssign").keydown(function (e) 
{
   if (e.keyCode == 13) 
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('input[name = butAssignProd]').click();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to mimic a click on a button when the enter key is pressed? If so you may need to use the `trigger` syntax.

Try changing

```
$('input[name = butAssignProd]').click();
```

to

```
$('input[name = butAssignProd]').trigger("click");
```

If this isn't the problem then try taking a second look at your key capture syntax by looking at the solutions in this post: [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: From https://api.jquery.com/click/ - This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "click" ) in the third. so that would do exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<button class="click_on_enterkey" type="button" onclick="return false;">
<script>
$('.click_on_enterkey').on('keyup',function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $(this).click();
  }
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery:  Fire Button click event Using enter Button Press
try this::

tabindex="0" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"

```
 <!--Enter Event Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function EnterEvent(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                __doPostBack('<%=btnSave.UniqueID%>', "");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <!--Enter Event Script-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
       alert('You pressed a ENTER key.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     $('#Search').keyup(function(e)
        {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var searchtext = $('#Search').val();
            window.location.href = "searchData.php?Search=" + searchtext + '&bit=1';
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the enter key on a dynamically created element.

```
jQuery(document).on('keypress', "[name=\"search\"]", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var _form = jQuery(document).find("[name=\"search\"]");
        window.location.href = window.location.href+'&'+_form.serialize();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
--------





    $('#eventClick').keydown(function(event){ 
        let idTrigger = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode || 0;   
        if (idTrigger == 13) {
            $('#eventClick').trigger('click');
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        }
    });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button type="button" id="eventClick">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

This appear to be default behaviour now, so it's enough to do:

```
$("#press-enter").on("click", function(){alert("You `clicked' or 'Entered' me!")})
```

You can [try it in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkfjvyok/)

Tested on: Chrome 56.0 and Firefox (Dev Edition) 54.0a2, both with jQuery 2.2.x and 3.x

Comment: This doesn't seem to catch a 'return' press at all.

Comment: @klokop You are wrong, this catches a 'return' or 'enter'. I've just tried it myself with jQuery 3 on FF 63, Chrome 69, Safari 10.0.1, and Opera 55, both on their link and on a separate site I created to test this myself. That's a +1 from me.

Comment: you are using a button, enter will trigger buttons and <a> tags but on a span say or as OP has a regular input field this is not the case.