# Add enter on event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following  in javascript. I would like to fire an action when the user presses enter rather than double click. How would I go about this?

```
$(document).on("dblclick", ".chooser select.right", function() {
move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
});
```

Comment: Presses Enter where?

Comment: `$(document).on("keyup", ".chooser select.right", function() { ... });` and check whether the keycode is Enter.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160342/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-pressing-enter-key?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Remove the `ondblclick` Event. Run your code inside `onsubmit` before you `return false;`, if you're using a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fire an event on a key press, change the `dblclick` to listen for key presses, and look for the correct key, in this case the enter key. Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("keypress", ".chooser select.right", function(key) {
        if(key.which == 13) { // enter key
           move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
        }
    });
});
```

Try it out in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uea0zqy/1/) (remember to press the "result" window first).