# Re-enable Enter key press on a text field

Tags: jquery

I'm using this logic: [Jquery: how to trigger click event on pressing enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160342/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-pressing-enter-key) to press **Submit** button on <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press.

But on a [web page](https://www.kvbnet.co.in) <kbd>Enter</kbd> key seems to be disabled as Enter key press isn't invoking the callback attacthed to `keypress` function:

```
var otp_fun = function (otp_sel, cmd_btn_sel) {
            $(otp_sel).css({
                'font-size': '2em',
                'color': 'red',
                'height': '3em',
                'width': '12em'

            }).attr('type', 'text').focus().keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    console.log("otp_sel len=",$(otp_sel).val().length);
                    if ($(otp_sel).val().length >= 4)
                    {
                        console.log("pressing eeee button");
                        $(cmd_btn_sel).trigger('click');

                    }
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("e.which=",e.which);
                }
            });
        }
```

**How to re-enable this Enter key?**

Comment: bind the keypress event to the body of the page

Comment: from what i can tell you are attaching a keypress on a function,why?

Comment: For god sake, please use short and meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the event handler to the `window` or `document` object:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("otp_sel len=", $(otp_sel).val().length);
    if ($(otp_sel).val().length >= 4) {
      console.log("pressing eeee button");
      $(cmd_btn_sel).trigger('click');
    }
  } else {
    console.log("e.which=", e.which);
  }
});
```

This will allow the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere to trigger the **Submit** button. If you want it to only work when focused on an element, change the `window` to the element's selector. **This code needs to be run before it can work, so don't put it in a function that isn't called immediately.**

Answer (score 0):

```
       var otp_fun = function (otp_sel, cmd_btn_sel) {
        $(otp_sel).css({
            'font-size': '2em',
            'color': 'red',
            'height': '3em',
            'width': '12em'

        }).
  attr('type', 'text').focus().keypress(function (e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if(key == 13)  //  Enter key Code 
   {
     $(cmd_btn_sel).trigger('click'); 
   }
 });
```