# Submit form with multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How to use jQuery to submit the form when you press enter, but to be sent by clicking on the second submit button. So that first submit ignored.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="inp">
    <input type="submit" name="first" value="first">
    <input type="submit" name="second" value="second">
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would have the first submit button if it isnt going to submit the form.

Comment: As i understand your question, this is already the case. Pressing enter, first button is used. Clicking on second one, then the second one is used/submited

Comment: I think you don't need that first submit button and just google trigger event key when pressing and u'll get a bunch of stuff to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160342/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-pressing-enter-key .

Comment: I need to submit the form when you press to enter, but to ignore the first button.

Comment: Do you mean when pressing enter, the second button should be used? Imho, still unclear what you are asking

Comment: Yes exactly when the INPUT text i want to press Enter to submit the form, as if I clicked the second button.

Comment: Maybe you will find it helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the enter key press, and instead of the default action to execute the first submit button action, force it to execute the second.

Handle a keypress action within the text input:

```
<input type="text" name="inp" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"/>
```

Then define your function `runScript`:

```
func runScript(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        //Submit action goes here
        document.getElementsByName("second")[0].click()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want *clicking* on either button to submit the form, but hitting *enter* to submit using the second button.

Here are a couple options:

**1) Change how buttons are displayed**

You can move the first button to actually be second in the markup, but change how it is displayed by positioning it differently. Note that you should also update the tabIndex if you do this.

```css
.firstButton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
}

.secondButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<form name="theForm" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" tabIndex='1' name="inp">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" tabIndex='2' class='secondButton' name="second" value="second">
    <input type="submit" tabIndex='1' class='firstButton' name="first" value="first">     
  </div>
</form>
```

**2) Change the first button not be a submit button and manually handle click**

```js
function submitForm() {
  document.theForm.submit();
}
```

```html
<form name="theForm" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="inp">
  <input type="button" name="first" value="first" onclick="submitForm()">
  <input type="submit" name="second" value="second">
</form>
```

Hope that helps.