# Submitting a comment when pressing enter in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i force a comment by pressing enter? At the moment when i press enter it builds a new line. I've seen quite a few articles here on SO but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's what I've tried:

```
function enterForm(event) {
     if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          runForm();
     }
}
function enterForm(event) {
     if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          runForm();
     }
}
```

---

Adding `onKeyUp=”enterForm(event)”` in the textarea tag. Didn't work.

I also tried something like this:

```
$('.cmnt_new').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
        // your AJAX call
    }
});
```

---

Comment: Use `textbox` instead of `textarea` or add `javascript` handler in the `textarea`, didn't read your code tho.

Comment: Dumb it down. Your event binding works: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/5JKy8/ the problem must be elsewhere. Also, this is a terrible thing to do to your UX.

Comment: The first example you show should work. The jQuery example with `$('.cmnt_new').on...` would work for any elements with `class="mnt_new"` _that already exist when that JS is run._ But you are creating the textarea dynamically, and you don't give it that class.

Comment: Thanks guys, I noticed it was working in the fiddle but i can't get it to work on my page. @KevinB,  I tried making the change to textbox and my textarea disappeared completely. Still stuck.

Comment: @nnnnnn Can you please elaborate on this? I'm still stuck.

Comment: <textarea id="cmnt_new" name="cmnt_new" rows="1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }"></textarea>';  I just realized my submit button was targeting the wrong button and my actual button that i need to target is just a styled div... can anyone please help. i tried using the comment function in place of the this.form.submit... like so: this.form.add_comment();  no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try keypress as found here:

[Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery?rq=1)

```
$('.input').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        jQuery(this).blur();
        jQuery('#submit').focus().click();
    }
});
```

Comment: The javascript works sort of but it's not actually processing my data.<textarea id="cmnt_new" name="cmnt_new" rows="1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }"></textarea>';

Comment: I just realized my submit button was targeting the wrong button and my actual button that i need to target is just a styled div... can anyone please help. i tried using the comment function in place of the this.form.submit... like so: this.form.add_comment();  no avail.