# How to submit text area by clicking submit button OR by hitting Enter?

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I can only submit my `textarea` by clicking on the submit button. I've also seen multiple posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery), on how submit the form by hitting Enter. However, I'd like to know if there was a way to implement both in one function.

Currently, I have: `$('form[name=userForm]').on('submit', function() {...}`
.

Comment: Think about user reaction though -- if I'm using a textarea, I don't expect it to submit on enter. I expect it to have a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call multiple event listeners in one function by separating them with a space.

In this case we're listening for both the `keypress` and `click` events, and passing in the event parameter to listen for which button was entered.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>

$(function(){
    $("#submit-btn").on("keypress click", function(event){
        var formValue = $("textarea").val();
        if (event.which === 13 || event.type === "click") {
           // Form submission code goes here
        }
    });
});
```

You could also do it with two functions. Inside the second one, you could ivoke the submit button's click event.

```
$("#submit-btn").click(function(){
    var formValue = $("textarea").val();
        // Submission logic goes here.
    })

    // Trigger the submit button's click event

    $("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            $("#submit-btn").click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Except that the `keypress` event is needed for the `textarea` not the submit `button`.

Answer (score 0):

Define your submit function and reuse it:

```
var submitForm = function() {...};

$('form[name=userForm]').on('submit', submitForm);

$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    submitForm();
  }
});
```