# Send message by hitting 'Enter' key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I designed a form to send message with a submit button but for every message i have to use my cursor to click submit.How do i send message instead by hitting 'Enter" key of my keyboard. Here's my code

```
 <div class="message_post" id="myForm">
    <form action="" method="POST">

        <?php 
            if($user_to == "new") {

                echo "Send a message to your friend <br><br>"; ?>

                To: <input type='text' onkeyup='getUsers(this.value, "<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>")' name='q' placeholder='Search Username' autocomplete='off' id='search_text_input'>

                <?php
                echo "<div class='results'</div>";

            }
            else { // MESSAGE BOX

                if($userLoggedIn == $user_to)
                    echo "<p style='margin-left:275px;'>You can't send message to yourself</p>";
                else {

                echo "<textarea name='message_body' id='message_textarea' placeholder='Send a message'></textarea>";
                echo "<input type='submit' name='post_message' class='info' id='message_submit' value='Send'>";


                }


            }


         ?>


    </form>




 </div>

 <script>    // Javascript to automatically scrolling down to recent message

    var div = document.getElementById("scroll_messages");
    if(div != null) {
    div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery)

Comment: PHP is not relevant for client side interactions.

Comment: is this all of the relevant code? If you have an `<input type="submit">` in a `form`, which you do, then hitting enter in the form will submit it. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLbxyd

Comment: You're using a `<textarea>`, which is a special case. If you want the form to submit when the user hits enter, how will you let them type multi-line messages? If you don't want them to be able to do that, change the `<textarea>` to an `input type="text"` and you will automatically get the submit-on-enter behavior.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. But after messages are sent when i reload my page a pop-up asking for resubmission pops, if i press continue messages are repeated again. So for each reload my last message is repeated.

So i added ' header("Location: messages.php");' under isset fucntion
but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript code to listen the enter key and sumbit the form

```js
$('html').keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which==13){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
});
```